# Coveo Page View Analytics Report

Tags: analytics, sitecore8, coveo

I have added the Coveo page view analytics rendering to a Sitecore 8 site, and can see page view events coming in on the Data Health tab on the Coveo administration console. Is there a way to create a report from the page view events? I need to create a graph/table of which pages are getting the most views.

I have tried adding to the Summary Dashboard, but I am not seeing options related to page view events.